# How to post the content of a file using Perl Script

Tags: perl, post

I am very new to Perl and badly needing for help.
I have a file.txt where I want to post its content to a webservice url.

This is the sample of my file.txt content.

```
Name: name1
Address: address1

Name: name2
Address: address2

Name: name3
Address: address3
```

And here it my post.pl (referencing from this site: http://xmodulo.com/how-to-send-http-get-or-post-request-in-perl.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $url = "https://domain/post.php";

# set custom HTTP request header fields
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $url);
$req->content_type('application/json');

# add POST data to HTTP request body
my $post_data = '{"name":"myName", "address":"myAddress"}'; // I want to post here the content of file.txt
$req->content($post_data);
print $req->as_string;
my $resp = $ua->request($req);

    if ($resp->is_success) {
    my $message = $resp->decoded_content;
       print "\nReceived reply: $message\n";
   }
   else {
       print "HTTP POST error code: ", $resp->code, "\n";
       print "HTTP POST error message: ", $resp->message, "\n";
   }
```

Using above file and script, how can I possible post the contents of the file.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `post()` method from [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) to make this much simpler. Underneath, it uses the `POST()` method from [HTTP::Request::Common](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request::Common), so you can look there for more details about how it handles file uploads.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $url = 'https://domain/post.php';

# The name of the file input field on the HTML form/
# You'll need to change this to whatever the correct name is.
my $file_input = 'file-input';

# Path to the local file that you want to upload
my $file_path = '/path/to/some/file';

my $req = $ua->post($url,
  Content_Type => 'form-data',
  Content => [
     $file_input => [ $file_path ],
  ],
);
```

You don't even need to open the file yourself - HTTP::Request::Common does that for you.

Comment: What if you have the content of the file you want to upload as binary data in a variable? (e.g. you got the data from a database) I'm having trouble finding the way to tell UserAgent to send that as file content, it is sending it as a string for a field which the server is not receiving as an attachment but as a field value.

Comment: @FranciscoZarabozo: That sounds like something you should post as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Read content from file like below.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

open my $fh, '<', '/path/to/file.json' or die "failed to open: $!";
my $content = do { local $/; <$fh> };
close $fh;
```

Or

```
use File::Slurp;
my $content = read_file('/path/to/file.json');
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, firstly, I'd like to say that the format your file.txt is in, is not a very intuitive format, because it's not in any standardized format, so we can't just invoke generic libs that do CSV or JSON parsing. Anyways, what you essentially need is to build a parsing function in between.

```
sub parse_file {
    my ($filename) = @_;

    open(FILE, $filename) or die sprintf ("Could not open '%s' (%s)", $filename, $!));

    my $string = '';
    my @args;

    foreach my $line (<FILE>) {
        chomp($line);

        # Assumes that every record is separated by a blank line.
        if ($line) {
            my ($keyname, $value) = split(':', $line);

            # Remove empty spaces left and right
            $keyname =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
            $value =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;

            $string = ($string)
                ? $string.', '.sprintf('"%s":"%s"', $keyname, $value);
                : sprintf('"%s":"%s"', $keyname, $value);
        }
        else {
            # When we have a blank line, store the string we have concatenated.
            push (@args, sprintf("{%s}", $string);
            $string = ''; # Reset the string for the next record
        }
    }

    close(FILE) or die sprintf ("Could not close '%s' (%s)", $filename, $!));

    return (wantarray) ? @args : \@args;
}
```

From the arguments that are returned from this function, you can then go

```
my @post_args = parse_file($path_to_your_file);
foreach my $post_arguments (@post_args) {
    # Call your HTTP request to set post_arguments and post the form
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you're worrying about parsing the file. All the question is asking is how to POST the file to a web service. It's up to that remote web service to deal with parsing the file and doing something useful with it :-)