# How to POST a local file using Perl?

Tags: perl, web-services, http, lwp-useragent

I have a server running a Perl webservice. This webservice generates a ~75mb .exe file.

I wish to make a POST request to send this file data to another webserver.

Right now I am using `LWP::UserAgent` like so:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

# URL to post to
my $url = "http://my.website.here.com/upload";

# Location of local file
my $file_path = "/path/to/file.exe";

# Make the POST request
my $req = $ua->post(
    $url,
    [ Content_Type => 'form-data', 'file' => [$file_path] ]
);
```

Right now, however, only the file name is being sent. I can see why that would be the case, but what am I missing here?

Many thanks!

Comment: @ikegami so you're saying the provided code is already correct? So no need to answer the question?

Comment: @Chris Turner, Ignore my (now-deleted) comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to [HTTP::Request::Common](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP::Request::Common) for the arguments to `->get` and `->post`.

```
my $req = $ua->post($url,
    [ Content_Type => 'form-data', 'file' => [$file_path] ]
);
```

should be

```
my $req = $ua->post($url,
    Content_Type => 'form-data',
    Content => [
        file => [$file_path],
    ],
);
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! I had originally followed the method format of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27502920/8538792) answer from 2014.

Comment: Fixed the linked answer.